# jQuery Address - Animate content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-animate, jquery-address

I'm trying to get an AJAX website with the jquery.address plugin

if you take a look at http://www.idbranding.nl the deep-linking works fine.

The only problem is i can't achieve a loading screen simular like: http://www.nerisson.fr/ (also uses the jquery.address plugin)

So my question is, does anybody knows how to animate the content (FadeOut/FadeIn) and show/hide a loading screen? I think it ain't hard but the documention of jquery.address is limited when it comes to animation.

Here's my code:

```
function loadURL(url) {
    console.log("loadURL: " + url);
    $("#content").load(url);
}       

// Event handlers
$.address.init(function(event) {
    console.log("init: " + $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
}).change(function(event) {
    $("#content").load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
    console.log("change");
})

$('a').click(function(){
    loadURL($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this as the load function:

```
$("#content").fadeOut("fast", function() { //block of code to be executed when page is faded out
    $("#loadingPlaceholder").fadeIn("fast"); // fade in placeholder (e.g. loading image)
    $.get(url, function(data){ // get the data and if data has been loaded...
        $("#loadingPlaceholder").fadeOut("fast"); // fade out placeholder
        $("#content").empty().html(data).fadeIn("fast"); // empty the innerHTML (--> prevents "flickering"), insert the loaded data and fade in again
    });
});
```

furthermore I wouldn't use the `click()` function, as you would have to apply it to any new links (that may be loaded) --> use delegate/on (don't know which jQuery version you're using) instead ;)

For a more detailed example check my version https://github.com/peter-m/blueprint/blob/master/js/pushState.js

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your help tremendously.

It's a start, now i have to implement into the current jquery.settings.js

Your github example looks nice but way to hard do code for me..

Comment: then..? If there's no "then", would you mind marking the question as answered? :)

Comment: i'm sorry i hit the enter button while my comment wasn't finished yet.. Any suggestions on how the complete code should look like (with the jquery.address.settings? I'm not sure where to place your code into my curren't code

Comment: just use it as your `loadURL` function - everything else should stay the same ;) basically if something should be loaded `loadURL()` is triggered --> it fades out the content, then it fades in the placeholder and loads the requested contents - if these contents are loaded it fades out the placeholder again, fetches the `#content` element with them and displays it again ;)

Comment: sounds great ! .. gonna give it a try.. if it's the solution i will mark it as the accepted answer ;)

Comment: of course you will have to add a `#loadingPlaceholder` element to your HTML or create it via JS, the proposed code won't do that for you ;)

Comment: i'm getting close, would you mind looking at my jquery.settings.js code? I think it's not correct.. it should load first .. then hide the loader.. then show the content.. DEMO: www.idbranding.nl (refresh)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11241/discussion-between-peat-ar-and-idbranding)